# Multiple dataframe dates and groups conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
            A    B          C   D  E
0  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  26 -1
1  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  10  0
2  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  16  1
3  2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-17  14  0
4  2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-03  18  0
5  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-08  37  0
6  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-06  29  0
7  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-10  20  0
8  2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12  30 -1
9  2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12  48  1
10 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12   0  1
11 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-01  19  0
```

*Wen* answered a very similar question an hour ago, but I forgot to include some conditions. I´ll write them down in **bold style**:

I want to create a new `df['F']` column, with next conditions, per each `B` group **and ignoring zeros in `D` column**:

- `F=D` value, where `A` dates are nearest to 10 days later than `C` date **and where E=0**.
- **If `E=0` doesn´t exist in the nearest `A` date to 10 days (case of `2002-01-28` `Rob`), `F` will be the mean of `D` values when E=-1 and E=1.**
- If there are two `C` dates at the same distance to 10 days from `A` (case of 2002-01-28 Mel), `F` will be the mean of these same-period D values.

Output should be:

```
            A    B          C   D  E   F
0  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  26 -1  10
1  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  10  0  10
2  2002-01-13  Dan 2002-01-15  16  1  10
3  2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-17  14  0  14
4  2002-01-13  Vic 2002-01-03  18  0  14
5  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-08  37  0  33
6  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-06  29  0  33
7  2002-01-28  Mel 2002-02-10  20  0  33
8  2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12  30 -1  39
9  2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12  48  1  39
10 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-12   0  1  39
11 2002-01-28  Rob 2002-02-01  19  0  39
```

*Wen* answered:

```
df['F']=abs((df.C-df.A).dt.days-10)# get the days different 
df['F']=df.B.map(df.loc[df.F==df.groupby('B').F.transform('min')].groupby('B').D.mean())# find the min value for the different , and get the mean 
df
```

But now I can´t get to insert the new conditions (that I´ve put in **bold style**).

Comment: Can you check your output ?Why Vic is 17

Comment: Sorry. Checked and edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mapper to

```
m=df.loc[(df.F==df.groupby('B').F.transform('min'))&(df.D!=0)].groupby('B').apply(lambda x : x['D'][x['E']==0].mean() if (x['E']==0).any() else x['D'].mean())

df['F']=df.B.map(m)
```

Comment: @Tie_24 m=df.loc[(df.F==df.groupby('B').F.transform('min'))&(df.D!=0)].groupby('B').apply(lambda x : x['D'][x['E']==0].mean() if (x['E']==0).any() else x['D'].mean())

Comment: @Tie_24 yw :-) happy coding